# Using "LETTERS" to add a row to dataset

Tags: r, data-wrangling, letters-and-numbers

I have a dataset that contains 301 columns. I want to add a row that contains a unique letter starting with a and repeats until the final column. What I have is:

```
DF:
Var1   Var2.....Var78  Var79...Var130V Var131
```

What I want in my extra row is:

```
  DF:
  Var1   Var2.....Var78  Var79...Var130V Var131
NR A       B       CA    CB        EA    EB
```

I have tried

```
DF[[nrow(DF)+1,]<- rep(letters)
DF[nrow(DF)+1,]<- paste(letters:ncol)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the expected output? What is `Var3, Var4 ...` etc supposed to show?

Comment: Have a look at `make.unique()`, i.e. `make.unique(rep(LETTERS, 5))`

Comment: I have 301 columns, Var1, Var2 represent the columns I have in my dataset. I stopped at Var130 and Var131 to keep the example I was using clean and uncluttered. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the same unique letter headers that you would get in "Excel" columns using this one-liner:

```r
c(LETTERS, c(sapply(LETTERS, paste0, LETTERS)))[1:301]
#>   [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K"  "L"  "M" 
#>  [14] "N"  "O"  "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z" 
#>  [27] "AA" "AB" "AC" "AD" "AE" "AF" "AG" "AH" "AI" "AJ" "AK" "AL" "AM"
#>  [40] "AN" "AO" "AP" "AQ" "AR" "AS" "AT" "AU" "AV" "AW" "AX" "AY" "AZ"
#>  [53] "BA" "BB" "BC" "BD" "BE" "BF" "BG" "BH" "BI" "BJ" "BK" "BL" "BM"
#>  [66] "BN" "BO" "BP" "BQ" "BR" "BS" "BT" "BU" "BV" "BW" "BX" "BY" "BZ"
#>  [79] "CA" "CB" "CC" "CD" "CE" "CF" "CG" "CH" "CI" "CJ" "CK" "CL" "CM"
#>  [92] "CN" "CO" "CP" "CQ" "CR" "CS" "CT" "CU" "CV" "CW" "CX" "CY" "CZ"
#> [105] "DA" "DB" "DC" "DD" "DE" "DF" "DG" "DH" "DI" "DJ" "DK" "DL" "DM"
#> [118] "DN" "DO" "DP" "DQ" "DR" "DS" "DT" "DU" "DV" "DW" "DX" "DY" "DZ"
#> [131] "EA" "EB" "EC" "ED" "EE" "EF" "EG" "EH" "EI" "EJ" "EK" "EL" "EM"
#> [144] "EN" "EO" "EP" "EQ" "ER" "ES" "ET" "EU" "EV" "EW" "EX" "EY" "EZ"
#> [157] "FA" "FB" "FC" "FD" "FE" "FF" "FG" "FH" "FI" "FJ" "FK" "FL" "FM"
#> [170] "FN" "FO" "FP" "FQ" "FR" "FS" "FT" "FU" "FV" "FW" "FX" "FY" "FZ"
#> [183] "GA" "GB" "GC" "GD" "GE" "GF" "GG" "GH" "GI" "GJ" "GK" "GL" "GM"
#> [196] "GN" "GO" "GP" "GQ" "GR" "GS" "GT" "GU" "GV" "GW" "GX" "GY" "GZ"
#> [209] "HA" "HB" "HC" "HD" "HE" "HF" "HG" "HH" "HI" "HJ" "HK" "HL" "HM"
#> [222] "HN" "HO" "HP" "HQ" "HR" "HS" "HT" "HU" "HV" "HW" "HX" "HY" "HZ"
#> [235] "IA" "IB" "IC" "ID" "IE" "IF" "IG" "IH" "II" "IJ" "IK" "IL" "IM"
#> [248] "IN" "IO" "IP" "IQ" "IR" "IS" "IT" "IU" "IV" "IW" "IX" "IY" "IZ"
#> [261] "JA" "JB" "JC" "JD" "JE" "JF" "JG" "JH" "JI" "JJ" "JK" "JL" "JM"
#> [274] "JN" "JO" "JP" "JQ" "JR" "JS" "JT" "JU" "JV" "JW" "JX" "JY" "JZ"
#> [287] "KA" "KB" "KC" "KD" "KE" "KF" "KG" "KH" "KI" "KJ" "KK" "KL" "KM"
#> [300] "KN" "KO"
```

To write this into your first row in `DF` you could do:

```
DF <- rbind(c(LETTERS, c(sapply(LETTERS, paste0, LETTERS)))[1:301], DF)
```